# Click element by textvalue with Page Object

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Is it possible to click a element by the value with the Page Object function?

I have use the Page Object with Id and Xpath before but never with the inside html.

This is my html:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 ng-scope">
    <label class="btn btn-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="product" value="5" class="hidden>
        <span class="h3 text-uppercase ng-binding">FASTPRIS</span>
        <small class="text-normal ng-binding">samtal</small>
    </label>
</div>
```

And was thinking something like this

```
[FindsBy(How = How.**innerHTML**, Using = "FASTPRIS")]
        public IWebElement btnFastPris { get; set; }
```

But `innerHTML` oblivious doesn't exist.

Is there anyway this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *xpath expression* to check the element's text:

```
FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//span[.='FASTPRIS']")
```

Comment: I have actually already tried the Xpath but it wont work for me.

Comment: Im so sorry... I had wrote Clear() instead of Click().... I'm such a rookie and your Answer is correct :)